# Send a script to the browser from C# back-end

Tags: javascript, c#, webforms

I have an alert that I want to send the user only on his first entry to the website. The condition is in c# and that's the code I used. It doesn't send the alret. What should I do?

```
if ((string)Session["alert"] == null) {
        Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('WELCOME to the website!\nEnjoy!')</script>");
        Session["alert"] = "done";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ASP.NET Web Forms u can use [ScriptManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('WELCOME to the website!\nEnjoy!')", true);
```

If you set the last parameter to true the content will get wrapped in script tags.

Your code would look like this:

```
if ((string)Session["alert"] == null) {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('WELCOME to the website!\nEnjoy!')", true);
        Session["alert"] = "done";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

ASPX

```
    <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:Literal id="ltrMessage" runat="Server"/>
</form>
</body>
```

ASPX.CS Code

```
if ((string)Session["alert"] == null) {
    ltrMessage.Text="<script type='text/javascript'>alert('WELCOME to the website!\nEnjoy!')</script>";
    Session["alert"] = "done";
}
```

To be considered, your literal item should be added to the end Body html tag.
I hope that helps.